# iOS 8 Today Widget and locked device

Tags: widget, ios8, lockscreen, ios8-today-widget

Sorry, my english is bad!

I developed a today widget. I need to launch Maps App (for example) from the widget and do not work when the device is locked. How to detect a locked device and launch the unlock screen in this situation?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("myapp://foo"));
```

Use

```
ExtensionContext.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("myapp://foo"), null);
```

The code is in C# using Xamarin.iOS, but the ObjectiveC-code is equivalent:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://foo"];
[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```